# ReactJS Loop Through Data in Async Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I have:

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="col-xs-9 job-list"><JobList /></div>
                <div className="col-xs-3"><RightPanel /></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
})

var JobList = React.createClass({
    componentWillMount: function () {
        this.setState({
            jobs: []
        });
        this.load();
    },
    load: function () {
        var self = this;
        qwest.get('jobs/list', null, {responseType: 'json'})
            .then(function (response) {
                var x = 0;
                var jobs_array = [];
                for (var i in response) {
                    jobs_array.push(<Job key={x} job={response[i]}/>);
                    x++;
                }
                self.setState({jobs: jobs_array});
            })

    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.jobs}
            </div>
        );
    }
})

var Job = React.createClass({
        render: function () {
            return (
                <div className="job">
                    <div className="job-header">
                        {this.props.job.id}
                        <span className="pull-right"><abbr title={this.props.job.dateCreated}>{this.props.job.age}</abbr></span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="job-body">

                    </div>
                    <div className="job-footer"></div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
);
```

qwest is simply a wrapper for $.ajax.

Is this the best way to output my components? I had to put the loop in the call back for the ajax as the call would often finish before the render function was called, so I would end up with nothing rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only going to run the load action once, it's almost acceptable. The problem is that if you load again later to update with new data, you'd get weird results. Keys should uniquely identify the component instance with the data that comes in. React uses them to not have to recreate components later on if they just switched position. You can read more about the reconciliation process with keys [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html).

I see in your `Job` component that the jobs you receive have an ID. Assuming it's unique, it'd be much better to use that as key since it'd work reliably even when you start making your component more dynamic.

Besides that you can use the cool `map` function on your response array to map them to your component instead of having to use a loop that pushes things into an array.

The end result would look like this:

```
qwest.get('jobs/list', null, {responseType: 'json'})
    .then(function (response) {
        var jobs = response.map(function(job) {
            return (<Job key={job.id} job={job} />);
        });
        self.setState({jobs: jobs});
    });
```

Or, with ES6/Babel using arrow functions (allows you to get rid of binding this to self):

```
qwest.get('jobs/list', null, {responseType: 'json'})
    .then(response => {
        this.setState({
            jobs: response.map(job => <Job key={job.id} job={job} />)
        });
    });
```

Another point: you should use `getInitialState: function() {return yourInitialState;}` in your component to set the default state, instead of setting it in `componentWillMount`. You can then change your `componentWillMount` to `componentDidMount` to start the loading after the initial render has been done (and, in that way, improving render performance).